# Should we migrate StackOverflow questions here, once out of beta?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I asked [How do I get some test USDC for use on Solana devnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940706/how-do-i-get-some-test-usdc-for-use-on-solana-devnet) on Stack Overflow recently - when/if solana.stackexchange.com comes out of beta, should they be migrated here?

Comment: In general, questions aren't migrated unless they're both off-topic/disallowed on the original site *and* on-topic/allowed on the destination site. So unless these questions are not on-topic on SO (and should thus be closed there, regardless), they shouldn't be migrated to any other site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will NOT happen. When a new site is made questions are not migrated from other sites. They also can’t be migrated since most of not all are over the 60-day time limit to migrate questions. And when questions are migrated all answers are lost which we do not what to happen if they are high quality and/or it has a lot of upvotes.

[Official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/1117855)

Answer (score 0):

OMG yes, that's a fantastic idea.

1. Click ‘close’ on your own question.
2. Select ‘A community-specific reason’
3. Select ‘This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network’

[image: A dialog that allows you to move your question to another Stack Exchange]

Comment: More detail here: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% practical, though, because unless you're a Stack Overflow moderator, you can only move a question to a fixed list of sites. Moderators, on the other hand, can move questions to any Stack Exchange.